# Regex String pattern matching

Tags: python

I have an array of https links which looks something like this

```
list1 = ['https://wvva.com/news/top-stories/2018/12/10/w-va-gov-appoints-former-beckley-council-member-to-parole-board/','https://www.starbreeze.com/2018/12/starbreeze-appoints-claes-wenthzel-as-acting-cfo/','https://www.streetinsider.com/corporate+news/perkinelmer+%28pki%29+appoints+prahlad+singh+as+president+%26+coo/']
```

I want to filter the link which contains `"appoints"` as one necessary keyword and `'chief-operating-officer','ceo','chief-executive-officer','coo','cfo','chief-financial-officer','chief-marketing-officer','cmo','chief-technology-officer','cto'` as other necessary keyword. I mean if the link contains words appoints and anyone of the above mentioned word like [cto,ceo,coo etc] then pick that link.

My sample output will be something like this:

```
['https://www.starbreeze.com/2018/12/starbreeze-appoints-claes-wenthzel-as-acting-cfo/','https://www.streetinsider.com/corporate+news/perkinelmer+%28pki%29+appoints+prahlad+singh+as+president+%26+coo/']
```

A regex for this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you show us what you tried, we can try to help you fix it

Comment: I tried doing this but it is looking for all the words that i mentioned in the regex
pattern1 = re.compile(r'^(?=.*appoints)(?=.*ceo)(?=.*chief-operating-officer)(?=.*coo).*$')

but I need appoints as necessary keywords and one of the mentioned words as other necessary keywords

Comment: Do you really need a regex? You could simply check `if "appoints" in url and any(word in url for word in ["ceo", "cto", ...])`.

Comment: I appreciate the solution and it will work as well but I am looking to build a regex.

Comment: But...why a regex?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a regex here. You can directly check for the existence of any item in the list of items to search in the urls list; if found, retain the url:

```
list1 = ['https://wvva.com/news/top-stories/2018/12/10/w-va-gov-appoints-former-beckley-council-member-to-parole-board/','https://www.starbreeze.com/2018/12/starbreeze-appoints-claes-wenthzel-as-acting-cfo/','https://www.streetinsider.com/corporate+news/perkinelmer+%28pki%29+appoints+prahlad+singh+as+president+%26+coo/']

list2 = ['appoints','chief-operating-officer','ceo','chief-executive-officer','coo','cfo','chief-financial-officer','chief-marketing-officer','cmo','chief-technology-officer','cto']

print([x for x in list1 if list2[0] in x and sum(y in x for y in list2[1:]) == 1])
# ['https://www.starbreeze.com/2018/12/starbreeze-appoints-claes-wenthzel-as-acting-cfo/', 'https://www.streetinsider.com/corporate+news/perkinelmer+%28pki%29+appoints+prahlad+singh+as+president+%26+coo/']
```

Comment: This is printing all the links. My question was I should only pick that link which has 'appoints' as one keyword and any one of the following as other i.e ['chief-operating-officer','ceo','chief-executive-officer','coo','cfo','chief-financial-officer','chief-marketing-officer','cmo','chief-technology-officer','cto']

Comment: Should the link having more than one of the "other" also to be picked or from the "other" list exactly one should be there in the link?

Comment: from the "other" list exactly one should be there in the link

Comment: Please find the answer. Updated just now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperately looking for regex, you can use this

```
import re
result = [url for url in list1 if len(re.findall('chief-operating-officer|ceo|chief-executive-officer|coo|cfo|chief-financial-officer|chief-marketing-officer|cmo|chief-technology-officer|cto', url, re.I)) > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your keywords to find the keywords that match in any of the provided links

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

keywords = [
    'appoints',
    'chief-operating-officer',
    'ceo',
    'chief-executive-officer',
    'coo',
    'cfo',
    'chief-financial-officer',
    'chief-marketing-officer',
    'cmo',
    'chief-technology-officer',
    'cto',
]

links = [
    'https://wvva.com/news/top-stories/2018/12/10/w-va-gov-appoints-former-beckley-council-member-to-parole-board/',
    'https://www.starbreeze.com/2018/12/starbreeze-appoints-claes-wenthzel-as-acting-cfo/',
    'https://www.streetinsider.com/corporate+news/perkinelmer+%28pki%29+appoints+prahlad+singh+as+president+%26+coo/',
]

new_links = []

for link in links:
    for keyword in keywords:
        temp = re.search(r'' + keyword + '', link, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        if temp and link not in new_links:
            new_links.append(link)

pprint(new_links)
```